# text not wrapping in card header

Tags: bootstrap-4, word-wrap

I can't manage to get the text to wrap in the header of the card.  I'm echoing out the card in php and it comes out perfectly except for the header which runs right off the screen.

```
echo '<div id="accordion">';
echo '<div class="card">';
echo '<div class="card-header" id="heading'.$collapseID.'">';
echo '<h5 class="mb-0">';
echo '<button class="btn btn-link collapsed text-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse'.$collapseID.'" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse'.$collapseID.'">';
echo 'Header: This just runs right off the screen....asdf jkl; asdf jkl; asdf jkl; asdf jkl';
echo '</button>';
echo '</h5>';
echo '</div>';
```

Looking for the header to just wrap within the header box and not run off the screen.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bare bones example with no custom class/CSS... the header text wraps fine; Can you reproduce the issue here in the code snippet area?

Following **code** works with the wrap effect as you wanted:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/img_avatar1.png" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">

    <div class="card-header" id="heading'.$collapseID.'">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed text-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse'.$collapseID.'" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse'.$collapseID.'">
Header: This just runs right off the screen....asdf jkl; asdf jkl; asdf jkl; asdf jkl
</button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title">John Doe</h4>
      <p class="card-text">Some example text some example text. John Doe is an architect and engineer</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">See Profile</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**update**: changed the bootstrap version from 4.3.1 to 4.0.1

Comment: Thanks!...the solution was upgrading the CDN to 4.3.1 as for some reason the 4.0.1 wasn't working